# reordering stacked bar-plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart, geom-bar

I want to reorder a stacked bar-plot based on the value of a specific level of factor-variable.

[my data in long format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vhv9lgjg4ifh4j/nlmelt.txt)

I want to group the stacked bars according the level `n.stem.niet` of the fill-variable (`stemmen`) from high to low. The normal stacked bar plot can be made with:

```
ggplot(nl.melt, aes(x=naam, y=perc, fill=stemmen)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.7) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives an alfabetically ordered barplot:
[image]

I tried the following three pieces of code for reordering my data, but none of them did give me what I wanted:

```
# 1st approach
nl.melt$stemmen <- factor(nl.melt$stemmen,
                          levels=c("n.stem.niet","n.stem.afw","n.stem.ja","n.stem.nee","n.stem.onth"),
                          ordered=TRUE)
# 2nd approach
nl.melt$naam <- reorder(nl.melt$naam, as.character(nl.melt$stemmen), FUN=min)
# 3rd approach
nl.melt$stemmen <- relevel(nl.melt$stemmen,"n.stem.niet")
```

It should result in a barplot with "Johannes Cornelis van Baalen" as the top bar, followed by "Peter van Dalen".

I might be overlooking something, but at this moment I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

A `dput` of my data:

```
structure(list(naam = c("Auke Zijlstra", "Auke Zijlstra", "Auke Zijlstra", 
"Auke Zijlstra", "Auke Zijlstra", "Bas Eickhout", "Bas Eickhout", 
"Bas Eickhout", "Bas Eickhout", "Bas Eickhout", "Bastiaan Belder", 
"Bastiaan Belder", "Bastiaan Belder", "Bastiaan Belder", "Bastiaan Belder", 
"Corien Wortmann-Kool", "Corien Wortmann-Kool", "Corien Wortmann-Kool", 
"Corien Wortmann-Kool", "Corien Wortmann-Kool", "Cornelis de Jong", 
"Cornelis de Jong", "Cornelis de Jong", "Cornelis de Jong", "Cornelis de Jong", 
"Daniel van der Stoep", "Daniel van der Stoep", "Daniel van der Stoep", 
"Daniel van der Stoep", "Daniel van der Stoep", "Emine Bozkurt", 
"Emine Bozkurt", "Emine Bozkurt", "Emine Bozkurt", "Emine Bozkurt", 
"Esther de Lange", "Esther de Lange", "Esther de Lange", "Esther de Lange", 
"Esther de Lange", "Gerben-Jan Gerbrandy", "Gerben-Jan Gerbrandy", 
"Gerben-Jan Gerbrandy", "Gerben-Jan Gerbrandy", "Gerben-Jan Gerbrandy", 
"Jan Mulder", "Jan Mulder", "Jan Mulder", "Jan Mulder", "Jan Mulder", 
"Johannes Cornelis van Baalen", "Johannes Cornelis van Baalen", 
"Johannes Cornelis van Baalen", "Johannes Cornelis van Baalen", 
"Johannes Cornelis van Baalen", "Judith A. Merkies", "Judith A. Merkies", 
"Judith A. Merkies", "Judith A. Merkies", "Judith A. Merkies", 
"Judith Sargentini", "Judith Sargentini", "Judith Sargentini", 
"Judith Sargentini", "Judith Sargentini", "Kartika Tamara Liotard", 
"Kartika Tamara Liotard", "Kartika Tamara Liotard", "Kartika Tamara Liotard", 
"Kartika Tamara Liotard", "Lambert van Nistelrooij", "Lambert van Nistelrooij", 
"Lambert van Nistelrooij", "Lambert van Nistelrooij", "Lambert van Nistelrooij", 
"Laurence Stassen", "Laurence Stassen", "Laurence Stassen", "Laurence Stassen", 
"Laurence Stassen", "Lucas Hartong", "Lucas Hartong", "Lucas Hartong", 
"Lucas Hartong", "Lucas Hartong", "Marietje Schaake", "Marietje Schaake", 
"Marietje Schaake", "Marietje Schaake", "Marietje Schaake", "Marije Cornelissen", 
"Marije Cornelissen", "Marije Cornelissen", "Marije Cornelissen", 
"Marije Cornelissen", "Patricia van der Kammen", "Patricia van der Kammen", 
"Patricia van der Kammen", "Patricia van der Kammen", "Patricia van der Kammen", 
"Peter van Dalen", "Peter van Dalen", "Peter van Dalen", "Peter van Dalen", 
"Peter van Dalen", "Ria Oomen-Ruijten", "Ria Oomen-Ruijten", 
"Ria Oomen-Ruijten", "Ria Oomen-Ruijten", "Ria Oomen-Ruijten", 
"Sophia in 't Veld", "Sophia in 't Veld", "Sophia in 't Veld", 
"Sophia in 't Veld", "Sophia in 't Veld", "Thijs Berman", "Thijs Berman", 
"Thijs Berman", "Thijs Berman", "Thijs Berman", "Toine Manders", 
"Toine Manders", "Toine Manders", "Toine Manders", "Toine Manders", 
"Wim van de Camp", "Wim van de Camp", "Wim van de Camp", "Wim van de Camp", 
"Wim van de Camp"), partij = c("Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", 
"Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", 
"GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", 
"Staatkundig Gereformeerde Partij", "Staatkundig Gereformeerde Partij", 
"Staatkundig Gereformeerde Partij", "Staatkundig Gereformeerde Partij", 
"Staatkundig Gereformeerde Partij", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Socialistische Partij", "Socialistische Partij", "Socialistische Partij", 
"Socialistische Partij", "Socialistische Partij", "Independent", 
"Independent", "Independent", "Independent", "Independent", "Partij van de Arbeid", 
"Partij van de Arbeid", "Partij van de Arbeid", "Partij van de Arbeid", 
"Partij van de Arbeid", "Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", 
"Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Partij van de Arbeid", 
"Partij van de Arbeid", "Partij van de Arbeid", "Partij van de Arbeid", 
"Partij van de Arbeid", "GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", 
"GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "Independent", "Independent", "Independent", 
"Independent", "Independent", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", 
"Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", 
"Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", 
"Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", 
"Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", "GroenLinks", 
"GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "GroenLinks", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", 
"Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Partij voor de Vrijheid", 
"Partij voor de Vrijheid", "ChristenUnie", "ChristenUnie", "ChristenUnie", 
"ChristenUnie", "ChristenUnie", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", "Democraten 66", 
"Democraten 66", "Partij van de Arbeid", "Partij van de Arbeid", 
"Partij van de Arbeid", "Partij van de Arbeid", "Partij van de Arbeid", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", 
"Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel", 
"Christen Democratisch Appel", "Christen Democratisch Appel"), 
    afk = c("PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "GL", "GL", "GL", 
    "GL", "GL", "SGP", "SGP", "SGP", "SGP", "SGP", "CDA", "CDA", 
    "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "PVV", 
    "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PvdA", "PvdA", "PvdA", "PvdA", 
    "PvdA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "D66", "D66", 
    "D66", "D66", "D66", "VVD", "VVD", "VVD", "VVD", "VVD", "VVD", 
    "VVD", "VVD", "VVD", "VVD", "PvdA", "PvdA", "PvdA", "PvdA", 
    "PvdA", "GL", "GL", "GL", "GL", "GL", "SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", 
    "SP", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", 
    "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "D66", "D66", 
    "D66", "D66", "D66", "GL", "GL", "GL", "GL", "GL", "PVV", 
    "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "PVV", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", "CU", 
    "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "D66", "D66", "D66", "D66", 
    "D66", "PvdA", "PvdA", "PvdA", "PvdA", "PvdA", "VVD", "VVD", 
    "VVD", "VVD", "VVD", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA", "CDA"), 
    stemmen = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L), class = "factor", .Label = c("n.stem.ja", "n.stem.nee", 
    "n.stem.onth", "n.stem.niet", "n.stem.afw")), value = c(38, 
    215, 19, 0, 25, 393, 68, 24, 20, 9, 430, 61, 20, 0, 2, 457, 
    14, 0, 20, 23, 236, 134, 76, 28, 41, 120, 256, 37, 13, 20, 
    426, 23, 5, 19, 42, 417, 22, 4, 33, 42, 424, 14, 9, 19, 44, 
    365, 8, 4, 16, 28, 242, 13, 5, 159, 95, 452, 19, 5, 20, 13, 
    390, 73, 24, 20, 6, 232, 129, 69, 18, 67, 427, 13, 0, 28, 
    46, 102, 353, 29, 5, 25, 84, 274, 27, 16, 23, 449, 19, 5, 
    15, 26, 323, 61, 20, 45, 65, 17, 97, 15, 3, 11, 352, 57, 
    30, 48, 31, 421, 22, 4, 33, 38, 466, 15, 5, 10, 13, 438, 
    23, 5, 25, 23, 455, 19, 15, 31, 0, 456, 19, 0, 30, 9), perc = c(12.7946127946128, 
    72.3905723905724, 6.3973063973064, 0, 8.41750841750842, 76.4591439688716, 
    13.2295719844358, 4.66926070038911, 3.89105058365759, 1.75097276264591, 
    83.8206627680312, 11.8908382066277, 3.89863547758285, 0, 
    0.389863547758285, 88.9105058365759, 2.72373540856031, 0, 
    3.89105058365759, 4.47470817120623, 45.8252427184466, 26.0194174757282, 
    14.7572815533981, 5.4368932038835, 7.96116504854369, 26.9058295964126, 
    57.3991031390135, 8.29596412556054, 2.91479820627803, 4.48430493273543, 
    82.7184466019417, 4.46601941747573, 0.970873786407767, 3.68932038834951, 
    8.15533980582524, 80.5019305019305, 4.24710424710425, 0.772200772200772, 
    6.37065637065637, 8.10810810810811, 83.1372549019608, 2.74509803921569, 
    1.76470588235294, 3.72549019607843, 8.62745098039216, 86.6983372921615, 
    1.90023752969121, 0.950118764845606, 3.80047505938242, 6.65083135391924, 
    47.0817120622568, 2.52918287937743, 0.972762645914397, 30.9338521400778, 
    18.4824902723735, 88.8015717092338, 3.7328094302554, 0.982318271119843, 
    3.92927308447937, 2.55402750491159, 76.0233918128655, 14.2300194931774, 
    4.67836257309941, 3.89863547758285, 1.16959064327485, 45.0485436893204, 
    25.0485436893204, 13.3980582524272, 3.49514563106796, 13.0097087378641, 
    83.0739299610895, 2.52918287937743, 0, 5.44747081712062, 
    8.94941634241245, 19.8443579766537, 68.6770428015564, 5.6420233463035, 
    0.972762645914397, 4.86381322957198, 19.811320754717, 64.622641509434, 
    6.36792452830189, 3.77358490566038, 5.42452830188679, 87.3540856031128, 
    3.69649805447471, 0.972762645914397, 2.91828793774319, 5.05836575875486, 
    62.84046692607, 11.8677042801556, 3.89105058365759, 8.75486381322957, 
    12.6459143968872, 11.8881118881119, 67.8321678321678, 10.4895104895105, 
    2.0979020979021, 7.69230769230769, 67.953667953668, 11.003861003861, 
    5.79150579150579, 9.26640926640927, 5.98455598455598, 81.2741312741313, 
    4.24710424710425, 0.772200772200772, 6.37065637065637, 7.33590733590734, 
    91.5520628683693, 2.94695481335953, 0.982318271119843, 1.96463654223969, 
    2.55402750491159, 85.2140077821012, 4.47470817120623, 0.972762645914397, 
    4.86381322957198, 4.47470817120623, 87.5, 3.65384615384615, 
    2.88461538461538, 5.96153846153846, 0, 88.715953307393, 3.69649805447471, 
    0, 5.83657587548638, 1.75097276264591)), .Names = c("naam", 
"partij", "afk", "stemmen", "value", "perc"), row.names = c(NA, 
130L), class = c("grouped_dt", "tbl_dt", "tbl", "grouped_dt", 
"tbl_dt", "tbl", "data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f9c22002d78>, sorted = "naam", vars = list(
    naam))
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `relevel()`.  Stop after the `reorder()`.

Comment: @Andrie I will edit my question: I tried these approaches seperately, not together

Comment: I truly don't know how to read your data into R, can you load it without all the quotes in every value? or just load a `dput` in there instead?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Strange, I have no problems reading the text with `nl.melt <- read.table("nlmelt.txt", sep="\t")`. I added a `dput` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decomposing your problem, it seems you want to:

- Extract the values of `n.stem.niet` in decreasing order of `value`
- Assign the factor level of `naam` in this order.

Try this:

```
naamLevels <- with(nl.melt[nl.melt$stemmen == "n.stem.niet"], naam[order(value)])
nl.melt$naam <- factor(nl.melt$naam, levels = naamLevels)
```

Then plot:

```
ggplot(nl.melt, aes(x=naam, y=perc, fill=stemmen)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.7) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx, that worked. Is there also a way to rearrange the parts of a stacked bar? With `n.stem.niet` and `n.stem.afw` to the right?

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished with

```
nl.melt$naam <- with(nl.melt, reorder(naam, 
    ifelse(stemmen=="n.stem.niet", perc,0), FUN=max))
```

Followed by the same plotting commands.